# DFS doesn't stop after finding desired item

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I have a class `Node`, which keeps a list of its neighbors. I'm trying to implement DFS in order to find the path from node X to node Y by recurrent asking if they happen to have the ending node as their neighbor and if not, asking their children (and if not asking their children and so on).

While it seems to be able to find that ending node and path to it (it does indeed print the path when I want it to), it doesn't end after finding it - using `return` or `break` doesn't do anything actually. DFS keeps searching other paths and I'm really stuck here - it looks like it queued those other DFS runs but I might be wrong. I want it to just stop searching when it's done.

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.connections = []
        self.edges = {}

    def addConnection(self, node, edge) -> None:
        self.connections.append(node)
        self.edges[node] = edge

        node.connections.append(self)
        node.edges[self] = edge

    def debug(self) -> None:
        print(
            f"I'm {self.name} and I'm connected with {self.connections}; my edges are: {self.edges}"
        )

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

n1 = Node("1")
n2 = Node("2")
n3 = Node("3")
n4 = Node("4")
n5 = Node("5")
n6 = Node("6")
n7 = Node("7")


forest = [ n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7 ]


n1.addConnection(n2, 30)
n2.addConnection(n5, 60)
n3.addConnection(n4, 40)
n4.addConnection(n2, 25)
n4.addConnection(n7, 35)
n6.addConnection(n7, 30)

def DFS(startNode: Node, endNode: Node, parents: list):
    global found
    print("------ DFS -------")
    parents.append(startNode)
    print(f"New parents: {parents}")

    startNode.debug()
    nodeChildren = startNode.connections
    connLen = len(nodeChildren)

    while not found:
        for i in range(connLen):
            if endNode in nodeChildren:
                parents.append(endNode)
                print(f"The path is {parents}")
                found = True
                break
            else:
                child = nodeChildren[i]
                if child not in parents:
                    mylist = parents.copy()
                    print(f"I'm looking for {endNode}")
                    print(f"I'm going to run DFS for {child}")
                    print(f"Found is {found}")
                    DFS(child, endNode, mylist)
                else:
                    break
        return parents

found = False

myDFS = DFS(n7, n1, [])
print(myDFS)
```

Comment: What is your *expected/desired* output?

Comment: @BeRT2me i need my DFS to return the path from startNode to endNode, which is stored in list called `parents`